# "/assets" missing from Rails asset_path in emails. It's different in two environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image_tag helper that looks like this in a layout:

```
= image_tag asset_path("logo/logo-02.jpg", :digest => false), alt: 'Some Logo'
```

In a staging app (preview app) on heroku, the asset_path is converted to this (correctly):

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/media-dev.some_host.com/assets/logo/logo-02.jpg
```

However, in production, it's missing the `assets` part of the path and it's this:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/media-dev.some_host.com/logo/logo-02.jpg
```

Any initial thoughts on where the problem is? I think the asset_path helper is different for some reason, but I'm not sure where to look.

We are using a CDN and in short, the images are located in `/assets/logo` and that's what we want the URL to be.

It's only broken in emails as well send by ActionMailer. Any thoughts on where the production configuration for ActionMailer might be incorrect?

Comment: Well normally what is residing outside your app (amazon S3) does not belong to your application assets. This may be the problem. Why have you not put the image in the app/assets/images folder ? (especially if it's a logo, it's not big and is used often)

Comment: So the logo is on s3. But so why would one application prepend `assets` to the path and the other app is not?